# $h(x,y)=f(x)+g(y)$

Tags: functional-equations

As a followup comment to my answer to the question

> $\;\;\;\;$[Can I split $\frac{1}{a-b}$ into the form $f(a)+f(b)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3308043/)

"Lord Shark the Unknown" made the following observation:

  If
  $h:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$
  and
  $f,g: \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$
  are such that
  $$h(x,y)=f(x)+g(y)$$
  for all
  $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$
  , then
  $$h(a,b)+h(c,d)=h(a,d)+h(c,b)$$
  for all
  $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{R}$
  .

My question is about the converse.

To keep it simple, I'll assume the domain of $h$ is $\mathbb{Z}^2$.

Explicitly, the question is this:

  If
  $h:\mathbb{Z}^2\to\mathbb{Z}$
  is such that
  $$h(a,b)+h(c,d)=h(a,d)+h(c,b)$$
  for all
  $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{Z}$
  , must there exist functions
  $f,g:\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}$
  such that
  $$h(x,y)=f(x)+g(y)$$
  for all
  $x,y\in\mathbb{Z}$
  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some rearranging shows that such a function $h$ also satisfies
$$h(a,b)-h(a,d)=h(c,b)-h(c,d),$$
$$h(a,b)-h(c,b)=h(a,d)-h(c,d),$$
for all $a,b,c,d\in\Bbb{Z}$, which means that for all $m,n\in\Bbb{Z}$ the functions
$$h_{m,n}(k):=h(k,m)-h(k,n),$$
$$h^{m,n}(k):=h(m,k)-h(n,k),$$
are constant. This means
$$h(x,y)=h(x,0)+h_{y,0}(x)=h(x,0)+h_{y,0},$$
so setting $f(x):=h(x,0)$ and $g(y):=h_{y,0}$ yields the desired identity
$$h(x,y)=f(x)+g(y).$$

Answer (score 1):

You say that for all $(a,b) \in \mathbb{Z}^2$ $h(a,b) \in \mathbb{Z}^2$. But, the functions $f$ and $g$ have their values in $\mathbb{Z}$. Do you see the non-sense ?

Comment: -1 This is a good comment but a poor answer.

Comment: @kakarotto: It was a typo (now fixed): Thanks for alerting me.

Comment: @Servaes I cannot comment... so please be kind and remove your -1

Comment: @kakarotto: No worries.

Comment: @kakarotto Done.